# Markov Chain with two states

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

A Markov Chain has two states, $A$ and $B$, and the following probabilities: If it starts at $A$, it stays at $A$ with probability $\frac13$ and moves to $B$ with probability $\frac23$; if it starts at $B$, it stays at $B$ with probability $\frac15$ and moves to $A$ with probability $\frac45$. Let $X_n$ denote the state of the process at step $n$, $n=0,1,2,...$. If the process is equally likely to start in each state at time $0$, find the probability that $X_1 = X_2$.

I know that the transition matrix looks like this: $ P = [\frac13 ,  \frac23; \frac15 , \frac45]$ but I am not sure what to do next.

Please help :)

---

If someone could check me, I got a final answer of $0.504741$.

Comment: OK, you know what the transition matrix looks like; do you know what it *does*?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you have the wrong transition matrix. You want $P$ to be such that

$$P{1\brack 0}={\frac{1}{3}\brack \frac{2}{3}}\;,$$

meaning that if you start with something in-state $A$, after one transition it’s still in state $A$ with probability $\frac13$ and in-state $B$ with probability $\frac23$. Similarly, you want

$$P{0\brack 1}={4/5\brack 1/5}\;,$$

meaning that if you start with something in state $B$, after one transition it’s still in state $B$ with probability $\frac15$ and has moved over to state $A$ with probability $\frac45$. This means that you want

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1/3&4/5\\2/3&1/5\end{bmatrix}\;.$$

For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $B_n$ be the $2\times 1$ matrix whose top entry is the probability that $X_n$ is $A$, and whose bottom entry is the probability that $X_n$ is $B$. You’re told that $$B_0={1/2\brack1/2}\;:$$ the process is equally likely to start in each of the states, so initially it’s in each state with probability $\frac12$. You also know that $B_{n+1}=PB_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$: that’s simply how the Markov process works. Thus,

$$B_1=\begin{bmatrix}1/3&4/5\\2/3&1/5\end{bmatrix}B_0=\begin{bmatrix}1/3&4/5\\2/3&1/5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\1/2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}17/30\\13/30\end{bmatrix}\;,$$

where I’ll leave the conclusion of the calculation to you.

Once you have this, you need to find the probability that $X_1=X_2$. That’s the probability that

$$(X_1=A\text{ and }X_2=A)\quad\text{or}\quad(X_1=B\text{ and }X_2=B)\;;$$

can you find that? Remember what the transition probabilities mean.

Comment: $B_2$ is not useful to answer the question.

Comment: Because the formula for $P(X_1=X_2)$ that I can fathom (which is also the one your post leads to) does not involve $B_2$, only $P$ and $B_1$.

Comment: To get $P(X_1=X_2)$? Nope.

Comment: Did I say such a thing? The last displayed line is correct, and to the point, and it shows $B_2$ is not useful.

Comment: To compute $P(X_n=X_{n+k})$, one needs $B_n$ and $P^k$, but not $B_{n+k}$. Just write down the formula on a slip of paper and you will see.

Comment: Ahhh... :-) $ $

Comment: I still think that my transition matrix is correct - my notes say that the matrix $P_{ij}$ is the matrix whose (i,j)th components gives the probability that the process goes from state i to state j. So in our case, in position (1,2) of the matrix, we want the probability that it goes from state 1 (A) to state 2 (B), which is 2/3.

Comment: ((Five comments by the OP erased.))

Comment: If someone could check me, I got a final answer of 0.504741.

Comment: Recommend that you add your work (how you got 0.504741) to the question

Comment: By the way, one cannot say either that the OP has "the wrong transition matrix". Many sources use multiplication *on the left* (of the line vector representing a distribution by the square matrix representing the probability transitions), in which case the convention is that the sum of the *lines* (not the columns) of P must be 1.

Comment: @Did: Yes, but in that case the transition matrix would be the transpose of the one that I used.

Comment: what is ${1\brack 0}$ and ${0\brack 1}$ signifies here? two states?